# Prove that sequences $\frac{a_n}{b_n} = 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-writing

> Let $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ be positive real sequences such that $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{a_n}{b_n} = 0$ and $(b_n)$ is bounded. Prove that $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} a_n=0$.

Proof: Since $(b_n)$ is bounded it converges, say $\lim b_n = L$. Given $\varepsilon > 0$, then there exists $n_1,n_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_n - L| < \varepsilon$ for all $n>n_1$ and $|b_n-L| < \varepsilon$ for all $n>n_2 $. I Don't really know where to go from here...any hint on how to approach this?

Comment: $b_n$ doesn't have to converge just because it's bounded. The sequence $|\sin(n)|$ is bounded by $1$, but it doesn't converge to anything.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have enough info to infer that $\{b_n\}$ converges.

Let $M>0$ be an upperbound of $\{b_n\}$. For a given $\epsilon>0$, there is $N>0$ such that for $n\geq N$, we have $|a_n/b_n|<\frac{\epsilon}{M}$. Then, for all such $n$,
$$
\frac{\epsilon}{M}>|a_n/b_n|=a_n/b_n\geq a_n/M\implies0<a_n<\epsilon\implies|a_n|<\epsilon.
$$

Answer (score 0):

No need to write any $\varepsilon$ here. Let $L > 0$ such that $0 \leq b_n \leq L$ for every $n$. Then
$$0 \leq a_n \leq L \times \frac{a_n}{b_n} $$

By assumption, the right part tends to $0$, so by comparison, you get that $$\boxed{\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} a_n = 0}$$

Answer (score -1):

If $a_n/b_n \to 0$,
then,
for any $c > 0$,
there is an
$N(c)$
such that
$|a_n/b_n|
< c$
for $n > N(c)$,
or
$|a_n|
< c|b_n|$.

If $|b_n|$
is bounded,
there is a $B > 0$
such that
$|b_n| < B$.

Therefore
$|a_n|
< cB$
for $n > N(c)$.

Finally,
choose
$c = \epsilon/B$.
Then
$|a_n|
< \epsilon
$
for
$n > N(\epsilon/B)$.